# How can I convert the function $ g(x) = {1 \over (1-x)^2} $ to a power series and find the interval of convergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$ g(x) = {1 \over (1-x)^2} $$

I know that a power series converges to $1 \over 1-x$ if $|x|<1$

But I'm confused by the exponent in the denominator.

Comment: You use wrong terms: a power series does not necessarily converge to $\frac 1 {1-x}$. A *geometric* series does. Next, when discussing power series one should indicate around which point to consider it.

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to differentiate a power series for all $x$ such that $|x|<R$, where $R$ is the radius of convergence. Here you have 
$$
{1 \over (1-x)} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}, \qquad|x|<1,
$$ giving, **by differentiation**:
$$
{1 \over (1-x)^2} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}, \qquad|x|<1.
$$ since
$$
\left({1 \over 1-x}\right)'=\left((1-x)^{-1} \right)' =(-1)\times(-1)\times(1-x)^{-1-1}=(1-x)^{-2}, \quad|x|<1.
$$

Comment: I'm confused about the differentiation, did you just differentiate the denominator and pull the 2 out?

Comment: @Jay See my edit. Thanks.

Comment: @Jay I've edited again - the first sum had an unwanted/inadvertent factor $n$ in it

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can be bold and actually *square* the series for $\frac1{1-x}$.

For example, to find the coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$
\left(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots\right)\left(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots\right)
$$
we would match $x^k$ in the first with $x^{n-k}$ in the second. If we count all the contributing terms we get $n+1$ of them. Each such term has a coefficient of $1\cdot1=1$, so we get a coefficient in the product for $x^n$ of $n+1$. That is,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A000]{\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n}
$$
As for the radius of convergence, the ratio test says that is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Or use the
generalized binomial theorem
(GBT):

$(1+x)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n} x^n
$

where
$\binom{a}{n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (a-k)}{n!}
$.

This has radius of convergence $1$.

Replacing $x$ by $-x$,
this becomes
$(1-x)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n} (-1)^nx^n
$.

If $a$ is an  non-negative integer,
$\binom{a}{n}
=\frac{a!}{n!(a-n)!}
$
and
$\binom{a}{n} = 0$
if $n > a$.

If $a$ is a negative integer,
$a = -m$ where $m > 0$,
then
$\binom{a}{n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (a-k)}{n!}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (-m-k)}{n!}
=\dfrac{(-1)^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (m+k)}{n!}
=\dfrac{(-1)^n(m+n-1)!}{(m-1)!n!}
=(-1)^n\binom{m+n-1}{n}
=(-1)^n\binom{m+n-1}{m-1}
$.

The GBT then becomes
$(1+x)^{-m}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\binom{m+n-1}{m-1} x^n
$
and
$(1-x)^{-m}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{m+n-1}{m-1} x^n
$.

Setting $a = -2$
(so $m = 2$),
$(1-x)^{-2}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+1}{1}x^n
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n
$.

Comment: (+1) Normally, I would have suggested this, but I opted for the conceptually simpler, but for some reason more daunting, squaring of the series.

Comment: That's me - never do something simple when something more general lurks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n-1}$$

by using the ratio test 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$$ 
$$\frac{(n+1)x^n}{nx^{n-1}}=\frac{(n+1)x}{n}=\frac{(1+1/n)x}{1}=x<1$$
hence 
$$|x|<1$$